# How to use `model.predict` when the target is one of inputs in tensorflow?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I notice the layer `LogisticEndpoint` in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#automatically_setting_apart_a_validation_holdout_set . The document build a model like this :

```
import numpy as np

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(3,), name="inputs")
targets = keras.Input(shape=(10,), name="targets")
logits = keras.layers.Dense(10)(inputs)
predictions = LogisticEndpoint(name="predictions")(logits, targets)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, targets], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer="adam")  # No loss argument!

data = {
    "inputs": np.random.random((3, 3)),
    "targets": np.random.random((3, 10)),
}
model.fit(data)
```

My question is that how to use this model when inference , since we don't know the target when we use `model.predict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "LogisticEndpoint" is actually a layer. It takes the **prediction** and **target** as input, it can calculate the loss tracked by `add_loss()`, and calculate the precision scalar tracked by `add_metric()`.

The target, if I am not wrong, is actually the ground truth data.
When you make the inference (testing stage, neither training nor validating), you do not need the ground truth data.
Just pass the input to the model, then take the output as the prediction.

To make the prediction of the multi-input:

First, convert the multi-input into one array (maybe a big one).

Then make sure the shape of the array (or precisely, tensor) matches the size of the input layer.

There is a part of the code in TF2 I am using for multi-input.

```
...
 for view_id in range(1,9):
   ...
                img = self.transform(img).float()
                pose_2d = self.transform(pose_2d).float()
                img_con.append(img)
                pose_2d_con.append(pose_2d)
# then make the img_con and pose_2d_con two tensor.
```

Comment: It doesn't work . It raises error when I run ```model.predict({"data":data["inputs"]})```

Comment: @DachuanZhao. Please paste the error here. Your usage of ```predict``` is wrong, refer to this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

Comment: Sorry , I copy the wrong code ... It raises error when I run ```model.predict(
    {"inputs":data["inputs"]
     },
)```

Comment: And it doesn't raise error when I run ```model.predict(
    {"inputs":data["inputs"],
     "targets":data["targets"]
     },
)```

Comment: It means I should send the "targets" keys when I use ```model.predict()``` ......

Comment: @DachuanZhao Dear Dachuan, in my several projects based on tf2, I will make inference simply by running ```model.predict(x)``` where x is my test data without groundtruth labels.

Comment: @DachuanZhao Should you have any problem running this, you can paste the error here. I am just curious about this.

Comment: You don't understand what I really ask . In fact , if your model has only one input , you can use aa array x in ```model.predict()``` (like ```model.predict(x)```) . But if your model has many inputs , you should use a dict in ```model.predict()``` ......

Comment: @DachuanZhao Before, I have a project which takes several images to do 3D reconstruction. For me, I just view them as one concatenated array then pass them to ```predict```.

Comment: @DachuanZhao Just first convert the multi-input into one array (maybe a big one). Then make sure the shape of the array (or precisely, tensor) match the size of the input layer,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229488/discussion-between-frank-and-dachuanzhao).